# Automatically set default permissions on installed files for entire target

Tags: security, permissions, gentoo, ebuild

On a Gentoo systems, lets say I have a lot of my homemade components with one ebuild each (normal case), and I want to apply default permissions on files at installation phase.

Is there a way to automatically set/configure default permissions on installed files, without modifying each ebuild file? Is it possible to do this globally (one modification working for all ebuilds)?

I came across "libopts", "diropts", "exeopts", etc.., but it requires to modify each ebuild to set my own default permissions.

Comment: Sorry I don’t have time to give a proper answer, but it sounds like you might be interested in writing an eclass. eclasses give you the ability to share code and define default implementations of phases. You could take `autotools-utils.eclass` as an example, define a default `src_install` by defining a function `«eclass-name»_src_install()` and using `EXPORT_FUNCTIONS` like it does, and use a convention such as that function calling a function defined by convention in your ebuilds or doing default installation actions after checking for some envvar set by your ebuild.

Comment: I know about eclasses, but it's not what I'm looking for, as it will require to modify each ebuild. I'm looking for something to change default permissions on files at installation phase.

Comment: I understand that you want to avoid adding more boilerplate to each ebuild. But I think `inherit my-common-util` or whatever to all ebuilds would make them much less confusing if anyone else were to use them, though that is probably not your intention. Are you trying to make an overlay that could be easily distributed to other computers and get the effects or are you trying to just hack your one single system in place? There might be hacks you could do to do this by modifying your system or settings in `/etc` or something, but that seems ugly :-/

Comment: The only reason I want to do so is because I have to many ebuilds to modify, and some of them are not from me. It seems like there is no proper way to implement my idea "as is"

Answer (score 0):

[bashrc](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/portage/bashrc) to the rescue! This file is sourced **before** each phase of the build runs. The phase you're interested in is called `preinst`. This phase will run before installing the data to disk. So your code could look like:

```
if [[ "${EBUILD_PHASE}" == 'preinst' ]] ; then
    if [[ -n "${D} ]] ; then
        find "${D}" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod ...
        find "${D}" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod ...
    else
        echo "Error"
    fi
fi
```

NOTE: the code is not tested, use at your own risk